# How can I graph survey results in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to graph my survey results with the numerical values of the responses listed on the vertical axis and the questions listed on the horizontal axis.

For example, I imagine the questions noted on the horizontal axis as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, etc. On the vertical axis, I imagine the actual numerical values (responses) noted by a bar graph.

The possible answers use a 5 point Likert scale (very satisfied to very dissatisfied) that have a numerical 1-5 attached to them, "1" equals very dissatisfied.

How can I graph this?

Comment: Do you want to create the chart for a single survey response (i.e., from one respondent)? Or do you want some sort of summary statistic charted for each question (i.e., from many respondents)?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking for, you want a graph that shows, for example:

Question "I like ice cream":  40% strongly agree, 30% agree, 10% neutral, 15% disagree, 5% strongly disagree

Question "I like popcorn":  [array of Likert scale proportions similar to the above]

Set up a table in Excel with the questions in column A, % strongly agree in column B, % agree in column C, ... % strongly disagree in column F.  You may need to do a fair bit of copy/paste/transposing your data to get this table together.  You can also use the raw numbers of respondents instead of percentages.

Then select the whole table, and insert a "stacked column" graph.

If your question stubs are long (more than a few words each), you might be better off with a "stacked bar" graph, running the question stubs vertically and the data bars horizontally.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Questions in column A, actual responses for each question in column B. Select the entire range, then choose a bar graph. You can edit the graph by right-clicking on it.